# Creating a chart with Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

This is **my view**:

(Chart related code ends at the asterix line created)

```
Ext.define('denovoeye.view.OcularPressure', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'ocularPressure',
    config: {
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical'
        },
        items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                fullscreen: true,
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [{
                        style: 'background-color:#72D2D4;',
                        flex: 1,
                        items: [{
                                xtype: 'component',
                                flex: 1,
                                html: '<div style="text-align:left;padding : 20px 0px 0px 20px;color:#120963;"> INTRA OCULAR PRESSURE</div>',
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'chart',
                                store: 'OcularPressure',
                                flex: 5,
                                layout: 'fit',
                                animate: false,
                                interactions: ['panzoom'],
                                series: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'line',
                                        xField: 'name',
                                        yField: 'g1',
                                        title: 'Line1',
                                        style: {
                                            lineWidth: 2,
                                            stroke: 'rgba(0,40,170,0.7)'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        type: 'line',
                                        xField: 'name',
                                        yField: 'g2',
                                        title: 'Line2',
                                        style: {
                                            lineWidth: 2,
                                            stroke: 'rgba(80,40,170,0.7)'
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                axes: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'numeric',
                                        position: 'left',
                                        grid: true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        type: 'category',
                                        position: 'bottom',
                                        grid: true,
                                        visibleRange: [0, 0.5]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }, 
        //******************************************************************************************
                            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                flex: 1,
                                layout: 'hbox',
                                style: 'margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;',
                                items: [{
                                        html: ' ',
                                        flex: 1.25
                                    }, {
                                        html: '<div style="text-align:left;padding : 20px 0px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">&#x025FC Right Eye</div>',
                                        flex: 1
                                    }, {
                                        html: '<div style="text-align:left;padding : 20px 0px 0px 20px;color:#ffffff;">&#x025FC Left Eye</div>',
                                        flex: 1
                                    }]
                            }]
                    },
                    {
                        style: 'background-color: #ffffff;',
                        flex: 1,
                        items: [{
                                xtype: 'container',
                                flex: 1,
                                layout: 'hbox',
                                style: 'margin:20px 20px 10px 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #c7c7c7;',
                                items: [{
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        flex: 1.25,
                                        html: ' '
                                    }, {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;margin : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;"><b>Right Eye</b></div>'
                                    }, {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;margin : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;"><b>Left Eye</b></div>'
                                    }]
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                flex: 1,
                                layout: 'hbox',
                                style: 'margin:0px 20px 0px 10px;border-bottom:1px solid #c7c7c7;',
                                items: [{
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1.3,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">APR 4,2014</div>'
                                    }, {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">10mmHG</div>'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">12mmHG</div>'
                                    }]
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                flex: 1,
                                layout: 'hbox',
                                style: 'margin:0px 20px 0px 10px;border-bottom:1px solid #c7c7c7;',
                                items: [{
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1.3,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">APR 4,2014</div>'
                                    }, {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">10mmHG</div>'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">12mmHG</div>'
                                    }]
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                flex: 1,
                                layout: 'hbox',
                                style: 'margin:0px 20px 0px 10px;border-bottom:1px solid #c7c7c7;',
                                items: [{
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1.3,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">APR 4,2014</div>'
                                    }, {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">10mmHG</div>'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'hbox',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        html: '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid white;text-align:left;padding : 20px 20px 0px 20px;color:#120963;">12mmHG</div>'
                                    }]
                            }]
                    }
                ]
            }]
    }
});
```

This is **my model:**

```
Ext.define('denovoeye.model.OcularPressure', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'g1', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'g2', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'g3', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'g4', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'g5', type: 'int'}

        ]
    }
});
```

This is **my store:**

```
Ext.define('denovoeye.store.OcularPressure', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'denovoeye.model.OcularPressure',
        data: [
            {"name": "Item-0", "g1": 18.341524994680185, "g2": 0.04297258032918805, "g3": 22.351114037029276, "g4": 10.501821959142115, "g5": 18.422488416954124},
            {"name": "Item-2", "g1": 1.9082894708999651, "g2": 5.729225849931112, "g3": 14.809082259901247, "g4": 38.935629377514275, "g5": 2.7729804343737},
            {"name": "Item-3", "g1": 21.372004559042896, "g2": 2.131323680889345, "g3": 12.98075950737056, "g4": 63.8279558143009, "g5": 18.852890370148263},
            {"name": "Item-4", "g1": 2.678644589238747, "g2": 8.533478458163483, "g3": 4.442247207672851, "g4": 87.39642008886551, "g5": 27.236700916073737},
        ]
    }
});
```

Am ending up with this error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of null`

Can anyone take a look at this and help me render the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
All i need to add was the chart height and width.

```
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    xtype: 'chart',    
    store: 'OcularPressure',
    flex: 5,
    layout: 'fit',
    animate: false,
    interactions: ['panzoom']
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a typo:-

Change the store name from `"OcularPressure"` to `"OcularPressures"` and replace it in the view as well. Also remove the warnings by adding all the required files needed in the view.

Comment: I don't understand,why change the name?
I have provided all the store and view name's correctly,or am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry the mistake was from my side. I ran your code but its not giving me any error. Maybe clear your browser's cache and ran it again

Comment: It still has the same error for me though. I don't see anything wrong though.

Comment: Yes its working perfectly on my side. Well the last thing that you can do is create another project and copy the codes. I cant help you any further, sorry.

Comment: The chart came as output?